# Prevent adding new csproj from adding AnyCPU back to solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

We have a solution that we only want to have the `x86` platform but every time we add a new project to the solution it adds `AnyCPU` back for every single project in the solution. This is tedious to remove all the `AnyCPU` lines in the solution file because we have 70+ projects in the solution. Is their any way to configure Visual Studio to prevent this from being added?

Not sure if this is relevant but we are on the legacy project system and only use csproj in our solution.

**EDIT 1:**

The reason I would like to keep `AnyCPU` from being added back to the solution is because of warnings and issues with building with certain nuget packages.

1. Some of our third party dependencies are built against `x86` and it produces warnings with no codes when we reference them so I am unable to suppress them.
2. The nuget package I am specifically aware causes issues is CefSharp. It will fail to build our desktop application that references it if the developer selects `AnyCPU`. It uses the platform to determine if it should copy its unmanaged `x86` or `x64` dll.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the section of the solution that causes issues when we go to build. From what I have [read](https://aras-p.info/blog/2017/03/23/How-does-Visual-Studio-pick-default-config/platform/#default-platform) Visual Studio looks through this list alphabetically for a platform if one is not provided. This example is from an unrelated solution.

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    QA|Any CPU = QA|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
```

**EDIT 3:**

As far as I can tell Hans' answer is the correct way to handle this. I have looked for other ways to handle this but after looking on uservoice was able to find where this was [suggested](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2463093-stop-automatically-messing-with-my-solution-config) in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake. VS2010 is for a large part responsible for it, its project templates chose x86 instead of AnyCPU.  Fixed again in VS2012 but not otherwise repairing any damage done by solutions that were once exposed to VS2010.  Or helping programmers to get it right.

The platform selection is meaningless for C# projects.  You use the exact same build tools for any platform, the generated code is truly compatible with "any cpu".  It is the just-in-time compiler that locks in the target processor, it does so at runtime.  The *only* setting that matters at all to affect what the jitter does is present in the Project > Properties > Build tab.  Only the settings for the EXE project matter, libraries don't have a choice but to be compatible with the bitness of the process.

It *does* matter for C++ projects.  A lot, they use a completely different compiler and linker for each platform.  Necessarily so, C++ projects generate machine code up front and that code must be compatible with the user's machine.  Also the reason this got fumbled at VS2010, that's when the C++ build system moved to MSBuild.

The typical reason AnyCPU pops back into the solution is adding a new project.  Since they default to AnyCPU again, it needs to be added back to the solution platforms.

By far the best solution is to stop fighting the machine.  AnyCPU should be your preference.  Use Build > Configuration Manager > Active Solution combobox > Edit.  Remove x86 so only AnyCPU remains.  And do focus on what you want to accomplish, it is the EXE project settings that matter.  Beware of yet another trap, even though the default platform is AnyCPU, a project template turns on the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox by default.  Not any cpu anymore.  High time Microsoft fixes this btw, the 64-bit debugger and jitter have been stable and capable long enough to no longer need this.

Comment: I would stop fighting it but it produces warnings since some of our third party dependencies are built against x86. The warnings have no error code so I can not suppress them unfortunately. Also we are using CefSharps x86 implementation for example which will actually fail to build if you choose AnyCPU.

Comment: Focus on the settings.  It is not the solution platform name that generates this warning, it is the [Platform target] selection in the Project > Properties > Build tab.  Choose x86 there when you know that it will keel over on anything else because of native code.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. The intent for fixing this issue is that we are trying to prevent developers from doing accidental check-ins that prevent our build machine and other developers machines from building. I think gated check-ins are better option for this but unfortunately that is not an option. So I am left with the task of finding a means to prevent them from being added in the first place. When building the solution from msbuild it looks in alphabetical order in the solution for the platform so I think the solution does matter in this case.

Comment: I will add an example of the global section I am talking about to my post since it is not very well formatted in a commen

Comment: That would be another good example of why you need to stop fighting.  When there is only one platform then it can never pick the wrong one :)  The configuration name can be anything you want, build machines just build all of them.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You mean each project can know of `x86` only and I can allow the solution to put `AnyCPU` back. I could then put a conditional to say that if the platform property is set to anything other than `AnyCPU` to set it to `x86`. I can take care of new projects by making a template that has the conditional setting of the platform in it. Is this close to what you were saying?

Comment: Hmm, not so sure you got it.  It is but a simple setting, it doesn't need a template.  That has to be changed only on the few (if not one) project that has the dependency on the unmanaged component and generates the warning.  You'd better try it to see for yourself.

Comment: I get it now, you want me to change it only on our desktop project because that one is the one that breaks without `x86`. I don't particularly want the warnings from the other projects but we do still build with them using `AnyCPU`. One of our lowest dependencies depends on diCryptoSys.dll which is `x86` or `x64` and will complain if we use `AnyCPU` with it. Do you know of any way to avoid the processor architecture mismatch warning?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify. If I build a C++/CLI assembly 64 bit with x64 platform and then build a C# project that references it I should still always use Any CPU for the C#? So when I run the C# executable does it detect that I am using a 64 bit only assembly and only runs 64 bit in the run time?