# How to prevent Visual Studio from changing the solution file in the scenario of using a utility project?

Tags: visual-studio

This question is related to [How to code a utility msbuild project so that it depends on a "real" C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194062/how-to-code-a-utility-msbuild-project-so-that-it-depends-on-a-real-c-sharp-pro)

So I have a working sample code where there is a utility project depending on a "real" C# project. It works fine when building on the console. Here are the files:

```
C:\work\a [master]> tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume OSDisk
Volume serial number is F6C4-7BEF
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   run.ps1
│   Subject.sln
│   Utility.targets
│
├───Subject
│       Subject.csproj
│
└───Utility.Subject
        Utility.Subject.proj

C:\work\a [master]>
```

**Subject\Subject.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Utility.Subject\Utility.Subject.proj**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="Current">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MasterProject>..\Subject\Subject.csproj</MasterProject>
    <MasterAsmName>Subject</MasterAsmName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="..\Utility.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Utility.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
    <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == ''">Debug</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(MasterProject)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" />

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="ResolveProjectReferences">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DllPath>$(MasterProject)\..\bin\$(MasterAsmName).dll</DllPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="*** Good" Importance="High" Condition="Exists('$(DllPath)')"/>
    <Message Text="*** Bad" Importance="High" Condition="!Exists('$(DllPath)')"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**Subject.sln**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.30413.136
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Subject", "Subject\Subject.csproj", "{D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Utility.Subject", "Utility.Subject\Utility.Subject.proj", "{EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {4DD676B7-ECF7-413E-9FC6-D4ED7EC73889}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

And it works fine on the command line:

```
C:\work\a [master]> MSBuild.exe /v:m /nologo
  Subject -> C:\work\a\Subject\Bin\Subject.dll
  *** Good
C:\work\a [master]>
```

The problem is Visual Studio. When opening the solution in VS the latter modifies the solution file by changing the target platform of the utility project from **Any CPU** to **x86**. This causes VS to skip the utility project altogether. We can actually see it when using devenv on the command line. Please, observe:

No modified files initially:

```
C:\work\a [master]> git st
## master
C:\work\a [master]>
```

Run devenv on the command line:

```
C:\work\a [master]> devenv .\Subject.sln /build debug

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.3.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Subject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Subject -> C:\work\a\Subject\Bin\Subject.dll
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: Utility.Subject, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
C:\work\a [master +0 ~1 -0 !]>
```

Notice in particular:

```
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: Utility.Subject, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
```

That means VS skips the utility project. But it also modifies the solution file so as to skip it in the future:

```
C:\work\a [master +0 ~1 -0 !]> git st
## master
 M Subject.sln
C:\work\a [master +0 ~1 -0 !]>
```

Visual Studio replaces the lines

```
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

with

```
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {EA5BE444-40F0-4972-A03E-5B794FAECF21}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
```

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Q: Have you been convinced to move from aspnet_compiler to [Rosyln](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342126/421195) yet?  With regard to your current question, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310727/421195

Comment: I was just planning to investigate the Roslyn option, because of the answer to my other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103543/how-to-speed-up-aspnet-compiler-exe

Comment: @paulsm4 - I looked at the second link. How does it help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. 2 files must be changed:

**Subject/Subject.csproj**

This change is necessary because this file is a contrived example of a non SDK style project. Visual Studio is in pain because it does not find something that serves like a marker for it, namely `PropertyGroup` elements conditional on `Configuration` and `Platform`. So, here is the modified content of that project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D2CF0D00-8B1B-4FCC-AF4B-5A354044F786}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Notice the new lines near the bottom of the file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" />
```

It turns out, our utility project must have these as well, otherwise VS botches  its configuration in the solution file, so here we go:

**Utility.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- These two are expected by Visual Studio. Not needed when building with msbuild on the console. -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(MasterProject)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" />

  <!-- This target is expected by Visual Studio. Not needed when building with msbuild on the console. -->
  <Target Name="CreateManifestResourceNames" />

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="ResolveProjectReferences">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DllPath>$(MasterProject)\..\bin\$(MasterAsmName).dll</DllPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="*** Good" Importance="High" Condition="Exists('$(DllPath)')"/>
    <Message Text="*** Bad" Importance="High" Condition="!Exists('$(DllPath)')"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Two changes are needed here. First, the same markers as in the previous file:

```
  <!-- These two are expected by Visual Studio. Not needed when building with msbuild on the console. -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" />
```

In the previous file these markers were less critical, but in here they are what makes all the difference.

And the second change:

```
  <!-- This target is expected by Visual Studio. Not needed when building with msbuild on the console. -->
  <Target Name="CreateManifestResourceNames" />
```

With these two changes it all works. However, there is also a weird catch with the solution file. One must make sure not to mess with the indentation in that file. It must be tabs, not spaces! I have noticed a weird thing. At the end of this file I have these lines:

```
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {4DD676B7-ECF7-413E-9FC6-D4ED7EC73889}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

If the `SolutionGuid` is not indented by exactly 2 tabs, then VS insists on adding a new `SolutionGuid` as if not seeing the already existing one. So, beware.

There is another nuisance - devenv command line hangs after having finished. I do not really care, since I use it just to demo the change in behavior. Anyway, here is the result after modifying the files:

```
C:\work\a [master]> devenv .\Subject.sln /build debug

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.3.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Subject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Subject -> C:\work\a\Subject\Bin\Subject.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: Utility.Subject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  *** Good
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
C:\work\a [master]>
```